# Mathematica envelope for the bottom of a plot, a generic function

Tags: plotting, fitting, envelope

I have the following set-up:

> xaxis = Table[x, {x, 0, 10, 0.01}];
>
> yaxis = Table [Sin[x] + Abs[RandomReal[{-1, 1}]], {x, 0, 10, 0.01}];
>
> ListLinePlot[Transpose[{
> xaxis, yaxis}]]

[image]

My questions is how can I make a line that very simply envelopes the function coming up from the bottom. **The envelope coming up from the bottom should be jagged such that it is a tight-fit (or overfitted).** Perhaps this could be controlled by some sort of smoothing parameter where 1: very jagged, 10: very smooth.

The figure below shows a plot generated from the underlying function itself which obviously results in a very smooth fit.

[image]

Comment: I already made this comment, but it was deleted, possibly due to migration. In addition to the other solutions offered, you can try something similar to what I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667323/mathematica-envelope-detection-data-smoothing/4668972#4668972)

Comment: This could be of interest too: [**Quantile regression through linear programming**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/177268) - see in comments below "quatile regression with B-splines for outlier detection in time series".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also create a moving min (and max) and use `BSplineCurve` to render a smoothed curve.

These could be made more efficient. They find the min and max over a window.

```
windowMin[data_, w_][pt_] := {pt, 
  Min[Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; pt - w <= x <= pt + w][[All, 2]]]}

windowMax[data_, w_][pt_] := {pt, 
  Max[Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; pt - w <= x <= pt + w][[All, 2]]]}
```

This function plots the original data with the `BSplineCurve` envelope. The parameter `w` sets the window width.

```
f[w_] := With[{data = Transpose[{xaxis, yaxis}]}, 
  Show[ListLinePlot[data, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[{Blue, Opacity[.2]}]], 
   With[{pts = Table[windowMin[data, w][t], {t, 0, 10, w - w/10}]}, 
    Graphics[{Red, BSplineCurve[pts]}]], 
   With[{pts = Table[windowMax[data, w][t], {t, 0, 10, w - w/10}]}, 
    Graphics[{Red, BSplineCurve[pts]}]]]]
```

Some examples...

```
f[.2]
```

[image]

```
f[.1]
```

[image]

```
f[.025]
```

[image]

**Edit:** In response to the comment, here is a more general form of `f` which allows for a list of xdata and a list of ydata provided they are of equal length. The min and max of the `Table`s are chosen to be the range of the x data.

```
f[xdata_, ydata_, w_] /; Length[xdata] == Length[ydata] := 
 Block[{data = Transpose[{xdata, ydata}], xmin = Min[xdata], 
   xmax = Max[xdata]}, 
  Show[ListLinePlot[data, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[{Blue, Opacity[.2]}]], 
   With[{pts = 
      Table[windowMin[data, w][t], {t, xmin, xmax, 
        w - w/(xmax - xmin)}]}, Graphics[{Red, BSplineCurve[pts]}]], 
   With[{pts = 
      Table[windowMax[data, w][t], {t, xmin, xmax, 
        w - w/(xmax - xmin)}]}, Graphics[{Red, BSplineCurve[pts]}]]]]
```

Comment: This works well however can portion {t, 0, 10, w - w/10} be changed, such that it works with any generic input Table: xaxis, yaxis.

Comment: for instance xaxis can be part of a Table that is obtained from a text file, the function should work provided xaxis and yaxis are the same length

Comment: See my edit.  The new version should work for more general x and y data.

Comment: The function works fine when the data does not have indeterminate values. The issue of indeterminate values is raised in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/max-of-a-table-list-with-indeterminate-values

Comment: As you mention, windowMin and windowMax could benefit from the functions MinFilter and MaxFilter.

Comment: With `Indeterminate` or say `Missing[]` values I would either drop them or replace them with some sensible value if you have some reason to believe you know what that should be.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a method you may be able to use.

The first part plots the lower 1.4 standard deviation over a moving average, and the second part makes a polynomical fit.

```
xaxis = Table[x, {x, 0, 10, 0.01}];
yaxis = Table[Sin[x] + Abs[RandomReal[{-1, 1}]], {x, 0, 10, 0.01}];
plot = ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xaxis, yaxis}]];
n = 100;
part = Partition[Transpose[{xaxis, yaxis}], n, 1];
dNeg[x_List] := {Mean[x[[All, 1]]],
   Mean[#] - 1.4*StandardDeviation[#] &@x[[All, 2]]};
d = dNeg /@ part;
env = ListLinePlot[d];
Show[{plot, env}]
```

[image]

```
d2 = Fit[d, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x];
Show[{plot, Plot[d2, {x, d[[1, 1]], d[[-1, 1]]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This method works well, however the bottom envelope must be such that it envelopes all points.

Comment: Furthermore this method is somewhat tied to the way the data was generated, i.e. a uniform spacing away from the mean. The function should work for any noisy data, which just simply envelopes the lower half.

Comment: @ akk - The spacing (1.4 std dev) varies with the moving average selection. The selection length is set to `n = 100` data points in the example.

Comment: This method is good！ but… why does the 1.4 standard deviation work? I mean… what's the theoretical basis of this method?

Comment: @xzczd - hi, the 1.4 was arbitrarily chosen, by trial & error, as it seemed to give a good fit.

Answer (score 12):

One possibility is going through the data with a window, and selecting the minimum or maximum value.  I'm showing code only for the case where the points are equally spaced along the $x$ axis:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[
  {data,
   {Mean[#[[All, 1]]], Min[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ 
    Partition[data, window, 
     1], {Mean[#[[All, 1]]], Max[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ 
    Partition[data, window, 1], Mean /@ Partition[data, window, 1]},
  PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thick, Thick, Thick}],
 {window, 1, 100, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another possibility is selecting the actual minimum/maximum points instead of taking the average for the $x$ coordinate:

```
MaxBy[list_, fun_] := list[[First@Ordering[fun /@ list, -1]]]
MinBy[list_, fun_] := list[[First@Ordering[fun /@ list, 1]]]

Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[
  {data,
   MaxBy[#, Last] & /@ Partition[data, window, 1], 
   MinBy[#, Last] & /@ Partition[data, window, 1], 
   Mean /@ Partition[data, window, 1]},
  PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thick, Thick, Thick}],
 {window, 1, 100, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this method works fine, could it also be done such that the number of points remain constant, that is the average is taken over each point for a window to the left or right?

Comment: @akk Yes, Andy has already done this, so I didn't change mine further.  Is there any reason you don't use Andy's function?  It's the same as mine except he wasn't lazy to implement the windowing properly.

Comment: Right, I was having trouble with the xmin and xmax constructs as some of my data is indeterminate. Looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

Given enough time, they will take all the fun tasks and make built-in functions out of them.  To that end, we can use [`EstimatedBackground`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedBackground.html) to easily find the envelope on either side of this noisy data:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[{yaxis,
   EstimatedBackground[yaxis, y],
   -EstimatedBackground[-yaxis, y]},
  DataRange -> MinMax@xaxis],
 {y, 1, 20, .1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the data is equally distributed, use `MaxFilter` and `MinFilter`. 
Compared to Andy's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/mathematica-envelope-for-the-bottom-of-a-plot-a-generic-function/2355#2355) it is much faster. I always try to avoid `Cases` as it is very slow. Apart from that is does essentially the same thing, with the difference that the radius window is given in data points rather than a radius given by the $x$-axis.

Comment: Would you add an example illustrating the functionality described by you ?