# Max of a table/list with indeterminate values

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Suppose I have a Table:

```
tab = {1., 2., 3., Indeterminate}
```

When I type `Max[tab]` I get `Indeterminate`, I would like instead to get Max of all points except the `Indeterminate` (i.e. `Max_new_version[tab] = 3`).

NB:
As a secondary case the answer should also provide a method to do a conditional replacement such that `tab` will end up looking like (i.e. `Indeterminate` is replaced by zero).

```
tab = {1., 2., 3., 0.0}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first approach would be:

```
Max@Cases[tab, Except[Indeterminate]]
```

> ```
> 3.
> ```

If I understand your second need, that would be:

```
tab /. Indeterminate -> 0.0
```

> ```
> {1., 2., 3., 0.}
> ```

**Edit**

Oleksandr's approach  is indeed very fast, for very long lists seems to be over 3-4  times faster then others. Since my first approach was quite straightforward, it is resonable to add another one obvious method which will be very handy (possibly the fastest) when we work with non-numeric lists :

```
Max@DeleteCases[l, Indeterminate]
```

This approach is only a bit slower for numeric lists than that by Oleksandr and probably the best for non-numeric data (when Indeterminates are exceptional cases rather than common).
To test prerformance issues we take a slightly more natural data, namely lists of real numbers with appended `Indeterminate`'s :

```
l = RandomChoice[RandomReal[100, 20000]~Append~Indeterminate, {10^7}];
```

and use `AbsoluteTimings` to compare methods, starting with the most efficient :

```
maxNoIndeterminate[l] // AbsoluteTiming                   (*Oleksandr*)
```

> ```
> {0.7070000, 99.9945}
> ```

```
 Max@DeleteCases[l, Indeterminate] // AbsoluteTiming       (*Artes II *)
```

> ```
> {1.1150000, 99.9945}
> ```

```
  Max@Cases[l, Except[Indeterminate]] // AbsoluteTiming     (*Artes I *)
```

> ```
>  {2.7720000, 99.9945}
> ```

```
  Max[l /. Indeterminate -> -Infinity] // AbsoluteTiming   (*cormullion*)
```

> ```
>  {2.8870000, 99.9945}
> ```

```
  Max@Select[l, NumberQ] // AbsoluteTiming                (*David Skulsky*)
```

> ```
>  {3.5120000, 99.9945}
> ```

Comment: For the first approach, how can you deal with multiple cases e.g. Max@Cases[tab, Except[Indeterminate] and Except[Infinity]]

Comment: the answer is a = Max@Cases[tab, Except[Infinity | Indeterminate]]

Comment: @akk You could use also `Cases[tab, _?NumberQ]`

Answer (score 22):

A faster way than those already given avoids iterating over the list to remove unwanted values, instead replacing `Indeterminate` wherever it appears by redefining it as `-Infinity` using `Block`:

```
maxNoIndeterminate[lst_] := Block[{Indeterminate = -Infinity}, Max[lst]];
```

Note that any list containing `Indeterminate` cannot be a packed array, so there is no reason (at least, not in this case) to replace `Indeterminate` with a machine number rather than `-Infinity`. The latter, of course, is correct for all possible inputs, whereas using any finite value is not. (Also, `Max[]` gives `-Infinity`, so there is a consistency argument to be made as well.)

Here is a timing comparison:

```
l = RandomChoice[Range[100] ~Append~ Indeterminate, {10^7}];

Timing[Max@Select[l, NumberQ]] (* 2.140 seconds *)

Timing[Max[l /. Indeterminate -> -Infinity]] (* 1.797 seconds *)

Timing[Max@Cases[l, Except[Indeterminate]]] (* 1.750 seconds *)

Timing@maxNoIndeterminate[l] (* 0.515 seconds *)
```

#### Edit

As the above seems a bit too trivial to stand as an answer by itself, we might as well generalize this to `Min` also:

```
withoutIndeterminate /: (f : Min | Max)[withoutIndeterminate[args___]] :=
  Block[{Indeterminate = f[]}, f[args]];

l = {1, 2, 3, Indeterminate};

Min@withoutIndeterminate[l] (* -> 1 *)
Max@withoutIndeterminate[l] (* -> 3 *)
```

Comment: Oh drat, I was about to post this method. :-)

Comment: Although this method is faster for the special case of Max/Min: to get the accepted answer you may or may not wish to add faster methods of the additional information present within the current accepted answer (which I feel answers the sub-question better e.g. (1) how to incorporate Max/Min ignoring +/- infinity values. (2) how to replace portions of the table. (3) how to get the maximum of numeric values only)

Comment: @akk I don't like to treat this site as a point-scoring competition and in any case I think these extensions are obvious. If you find them non-obvious and would like an example of how to do it, I will add that to my answer, but I will not do it simply to one-up someone else.

Comment: Ok, in that case I will edit the accepted answer (the one I presume most people will look at) to look at your implementation also.

Comment: I just looked at the `Intermediate = f[]` construct. Clever. It appears that I already upvoted this at some point, otherwise I'd upvote you now.

Answer (score 8):

One more way:

```
tab = {1., 2., 3., Indeterminate};
Max @ Select[tab, NumberQ]
```

> ```
> 3.
> ```

Answer (score 5):

There is one case else to be added (how rich is Mathematica!):

```
Max[Replace[l, Indeterminate -> -Infinity, {1}]] // AbsoluteTiming
{0.639738, 99.9987}
```

which is comparable (in my machine) to:

```
Max@DeleteCases[l, Indeterminate] // AbsoluteTiming
{0.627598, 99.9987}
```

And much better than the simple `/.` :

```
Max[l /. Indeterminate -> -Infinity] // AbsoluteTiming
{1.309642, 99.9987}
```

Answer (score 5):

But now suppose that you want to compute both `Max` and `Min` of a list containing `Indeterminate` (in other words, you want `{Min[#],Max[#]}&@list)`?

Sending `Indeterminate` to `-Infinity` is no longer such a great idea as you will get `-Infinity` for `Min`. And, of course, if you use `Infinity`, `Max` will not come out right.

Actually, you can use the same trick by replacing `-Infinity` with `Sequence[]`. Note that both `Max[100,Sequence[]]` and `Min[100,Sequence[]]` return 100.

Comment: Or you can set it to `Min[]` or `Max[]` as appropriate (as I did in my answer). `Sequence[]` also works of course; it might be more appropriate for functions without any extremal value such as `Mean` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this:

```
Max1[l_] := Max[l  /. Indeterminate -> 0.0]
```

so that

```
Max1[tab]
```

gives

```
3.
```

Comment: If you are going to define a function to replace `Indeterminate`, you really ought to have the rule replace it with `-Infinity` instead of `0.0`. After all, what happens if I pass `{-1,-2,Indeterminate}`?