# How to test for Indeterminate values?

Tags: core-language

I need something like this

```
a = 101010/0;
If[a == ComplexInfinity, True, False]
```

But if I use `ToString`, I get what I want.

```
a = 101010/0;
If[ToString[a] == "ComplexInfinity", True, False]
```

Does someone know a better way to do this?, I can't belive that transforming to a string is the only way.

Comment: This question might be interesting for you [Max of a table/list with indeterminate values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/max-of-a-table-list-with-indeterminate-values).

Comment: I think you want `SameQ` (`===`) i.e. `If[a === ComplexInfinity, True, False]`

Comment: The title says `Indeterminate` but the question shows only `ComplexInfinity` -- do you mean both symbols, or just one, or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the record, as RunnyKine wrote in a comment

```
a = 101010/0;
If[a === ComplexInfinity, True, False]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try:

```
a = 101010/0;
If[1/a == 0, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

A generalization could look like this:

```
{1, 101010/0, 2, 0/0, Infinity, -Infinity} /.
   ComplexInfinity | DirectedInfinity | Indeterminate :> True /. True[1 | -1] -> True
```

> {1, True, 2, True, True, True}

Comment: Or ... /. ComplexInfinity | DirectedInfinity[1] | DirectedInfinity[-1] | Indeterminate :> True