# Selecting a Point that has the Lowest Absolute x/y-coordinate From a List of Points

Tags: list-manipulation

Given that there is a set of points, for example, `{{3,4,2},{5,2,-1}}`. How do I go about selecting the point that has the lowest absolute x, y or z-coordinate from the list? In this case, the point selected should be `{{5,2,-1}}` as 1 is the lowest absolute value among all the points. Would the command `Select[{{3,4,2}, {5,2,-1}}, ...]` be good enough to perform such operation? Specifically, my understanding is that `Select[{{3,4,2}, {5,2,-1}}, ...]` is useful for selecting each individual point that satisfies certain condition stated in the command, so the question is whether it would be possible to compare 2 different points to select the desired point under the `Select[...]` operation. Or would there be a better alternative to getting the desired point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Min returns the smallest element of any of the lists, you can use Position:

```
list = RandomReal[1, {50, 3}];
list[[Position[list, Min[Abs@list]][[1, 1]]]]
```

Comment: I guess you will need an extra `Abs` before the `Mean`.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the lowest absolute part

Comment: I'd use `Pick[]` for the purpose myself...

Answer (score 8):

`Select` only looks at each element in the list to decide if it stays or it doesn't, much like `Cases`. Some options

```
f1 = Extract[#, (First@Position[Flatten@Abs@#, Min@Abs@#] + 2)~Quotient~3] &;
f2 = Extract[#, Ordering[#, 1, Min@Abs@#1 < Min@Abs@#2 &]] &;
f3 = First@SortBy[#, Min@Abs@# &] &;
f4 = First@Nearest[#, {0`, 0`, 0`}, DistanceFunction -> (Min@Abs[#2 - #1] &)] &;
f5 = Extract[#, Ordering[Min /@ Abs@#, 1]] &;
f6 = Extract[#, (Ordering[Abs@Flatten@#, 1] + 2)~Quotient~3] &;
```

So

```
f1[r] // AbsoluteTiming
f2[r] // AbsoluteTiming
f3[r] // AbsoluteTiming
f4[r] // AbsoluteTiming
f5[r] // AbsoluteTiming
f6[r] // AbsoluteTiming
```

gives

> {0.1760238, {-12.1516, 56.6547, -0.000243945}}
>
> {0.8061080, {-12.1516, 56.6547, -0.000243945}}
>
> {0.0430082, {-12.1516, 56.6547, -0.000243945}}
>
> {1.1661187, {-12.1516, 56.6547, -0.000243945}}
>
> {0.0150015, {-12.1516, 56.6547, -0.000243945}}
>
> {0.0060008, {-12.1516, 56.6547, -0.000243945}}

Comment: Interesting comparisons. For your last one, `f6`, I got an additional speed boost by omitting the unused coordinates from the argument of `Ordering`: `f7=Extract[#1,Ordering[Abs[#1[[All,1]]],1]]&`.

Comment: @Jens, I understood he wanted the minimum abs of any of the three coordinates, your suggested code would only look at the first one, right?

Comment: Oh, right. I'm solving a different problem - If I do my approach for each component separately, I think your f6 wins the speed comparison again.

Answer (score 3):

There's a little function I call `MinBy` I like to use from time to time ([see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2354/12)).  It relates to `Min` the same way `SortBy` relates to `Sort`.

```
MinBy[list_, fun_] := list[[First@Ordering[fun /@ list, 1]]]
```

This function gives yet another simple solution to your question:

```
points = {{3, 4, 2}, {5, 2, -1}}
MinBy[points, Composition[Min, Abs]]
```

Note that an inherent problem with using `MinBy` is that is always returns only a single result, even if there are several equivalent elements of the list that could be considered minimal.  This solution will always return only a single point.