# Integrating curve peaks

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, peak-detection

I have curve with a set of peaks (black line in the figure below) and I have to calculate the area of each peak.  At the end of each peak there is a short linear region. So to calculate peaks' area first I should calculate the curve which pass smoothly through all linear regions of my initial curve (red line). I know I should provide some code where I attempt to solve the problem, but I have no any idea how to do it, sorry.

I would like to precise that I need to calculate this red curve, but not just integrate. I need just model this calculations in Mathematica to reproduce it further using JavaScript.

[image]

Here is data for my curve

```
data = << "http://pastebin.com/raw/kAdkHpQn";
```

The shape of peaks could be very different. Moreover it could be several maximums inside one peak. The only definite thing is that there is linear region after each peak. A add some more examples of my curves

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/mathematica-envelope-for-the-bottom-of-a-plot-a-generic-function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data = << "http://pastebin.com/raw/kAdkHpQn";

ip = Interpolation[data];

base = FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]], 1, 0, 19.3] /. {x_, y_} -> {2 x, y};

ipBase = Interpolation[base, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot[{ip[x], ipBase[x]}, {x, 2, 3298}, Epilog -> Point[base]]

ni = NIntegrate[ip[x], {x, 2, 3298}, MaxRecursion -> 25, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}]
niBase = NIntegrate[ipBase[x], {x, 2, 3298}]

diff = niBase - ni
```

[image]

> ni= 63855.3
>
> niBase= 64013.6
>
> diff= 158.27

Comment: I need to calculate the area of each peak, but I also I really need to calculate the red curve, which I will also use for other purposes

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков Do you have the data for the Red line or is that part of what you are trying to find

Comment: No, I draw it by hands. I want to find this red line automatically

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков Take a look at my update

Comment: Very close. Thank you!

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков Now even closer

Answer (score 6):

Here is something to get you started,

```
{xvals, yvals} = Transpose@data;
yvals = -yvals;
background = EstimatedBackground[yvals,20];
ListLinePlot[
 {yvals, background},
 DataRange -> MinMax@xvals,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you have the background, let's find the peaks:

```
peaks = {xvals[[#1]], #2} & @@@ 
  FindPeaks[yvals - background, 10]
(* {{76., 0.0565933}, {294., 0.422362}, {494., 
  0.337809}, {694., 0.315474}, {894., 0.305115}, {1094., 
  0.294088}, {1294., 0.287829}, {1494., 0.281396}, {1694., 
  0.278064}, {1896., 0.264395}, {2096., 0.258708}, {2296., 
  0.253219}, {2496., 0.254073}, {2696., 0.247036}, {2896., 
  0.24627}, {3096., 0.236166}, {3296., 0.231089}} *)
```

Take a look to make sure you found all the peaks:

```
ListLinePlot[yvals - background,
 DataRange -> MinMax@xvals,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@peaks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now if I wanted to find the peak areas, I might try to fit this data to a functional form, perhaps a Gaussian for each peak, or a Lorentzian.  Have a look at [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html)

Of course, you **could** do it purely numerically by integrating an interpolating function between the midpoints of all the peaks...

```
interp = Interpolation[Thread[{xvals, yvals - background}]];
midpoints = 
  Join[{First@xvals}, Mean /@ Partition[peaks[[All, 1]], 2, 1]];
ListLinePlot[yvals - background,
 DataRange -> MinMax@xvals,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@peaks, Blue, 
   Point[{#, interp@#} & /@ midpoints]},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
peakAreas = 
 Integrate[interp[x], {x, #1, #2}] & @@@ Partition[midpoints, 2, 1]
(* {2.17032, 18.192, 12.8656, 11.233, 10.8508, 10.5048, \
10.2787, 10.2621, 10.4438, 9.58863, 9.48917, 9.15292, 9.03857, \
8.9062, 8.74465, 8.51919} *)
```

Comment: Very nice! But unfortunately the shape of peaks could be very different. Moreover it could be several maximums inside one peak. The only definite thing is that there is linear region after each peak.

Comment: Like I said, I was just trying to get you started.  Perhaps you could try to do the rest?

Comment: Yes thank you. I will try